# Can I find the value of $x & y$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Find x,y from N such as $x^{(2y)}=1560-x^{y}$.Is it possible to find the value of x and y only from one equation.
please help me.I approached in different ways.But all my attempt went in vain.

Comment: If there are no other restrictions on x and y, then no, you can't. You can solve for x^y, however.

Comment: What is $(x^y)^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Quadratic equation:
\begin{align*}
x^{2y}-1560+x^{y} & =0\\
\left(x^{y}\right)^{2}+x^{y}-1560 & =0
\end{align*}
This is just a quadratic equation with solutions
$$x^{y}=-40,39.$$
Since you cannot take the log of a negative number (in $\mathbb{R}$),
the only real solution is
$$y=\log_{x}39.$$

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot (without restrictions) solve a system of equations with only 1 equation. You can however, solve for $x^y$ (as Edward Jiang mentioned in the comments):

to solve for $x^y$

lets say $x^y$ is $u$

$u^2 = 1560 -u$

$u^2 + u - 1560=0$

look familiar?

(beware of one of your answers: $(x^y)^2$ must be positive)

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x^y$. The equation then becomes $z^2=1560-z$ or $z^2+z-1560=0$. This factors as $(z-39 )(z+ 40)=0$.  Which gives $z=39$ and $z=-40$. Re-substitute the $x^y$.  A logarithm will help here to get $y$ in terms of $x$.